# RecylerView item views hiding/showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement the reclyerview to behave like following 
items by default will be grey color and the other button hidden until on button add click:

[image]

The expansion happens one item per list if any other item is expanded clicking on the next item will first close any open item and then open the new one:

[image]

I have tried to implement it but every time a single item clicked and the expansion occurs, then no other item in the list will expand even though clicking on the plus button increases the number on it.

Also the expansion can appear on all items while on the reference its only one item per click that expands.

Here is my code

```
public class SalesProductsAdapter extends  

RecyclerView.Adapter<SalesProductsAdapter.Vh>
    implements   
     TextWatcher,Filterable,View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener  
   {

   public List<SalesProductsItems> mItems = new  ArrayList<SalesProductsItems>();
   public static List<SalesProductsItems> filteredIt = new ArrayList<SalesProductsItems>();

   @Override
public Vh onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.selling_screen_sellitems, parent, false);

    Vh vh = new Vh(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Vh holder, final int position) {
    final SalesProductsItems cl = filteredIt.get(position);
    if(pitems != null && pitems.size() > 0){
        for(int j = 0; j < pitems.size(); j++){
            Pending_Items _pitems = pitems.get(j);
            long proid = cl.getProdid();
            long _proid = _pitems.getProdloc();
            if(proid == _proid){
                prodname = cl.getProduct();
                qty[0] = new BigDecimal(_pitems.getQty()).intValue();
                unit[0] = _pitems.getPrice();
            } else {
                prodname = cl.getProduct();
                qty[0] = new BigDecimal(cl.getQuantity()).intValue();
                unit[0] = cl.getUnit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        prodname = cl.getProduct();
        qty[0] = new BigDecimal(cl.getQuantity()).intValue();
        unit[0] = cl.getUnit();
    }
    items = pitems.size();
    if(items > 0)
        imgnext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        imgnext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.txtproduct.setText(prodname);
    updateViews(qty[0], holder);

    if(qty[0] > 0){
        System.out.println(" qty is " + s_qty);
        holder.imgminus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imgadd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.txtqty.setText(s_qty[0]);
        holder.txtunit.setText(s_unit);
        holder.txtsubtotal.setText(s_subtotal[0]);
    } else {
        holder.imgminus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.txtqty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.txtunit.setText(s_unit);
        holder.txtsubtotal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.imgadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qty[0] += 1;
            if(Products.checkQty(context,cl.getProdid(),qty[0])) {
                if (qty[0] == 1) {
                    s_qty[0] = String.valueOf(qty[0]);

                    holder.txtqty.setText(s_qty[0]);
                    holder.txtqty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgminus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    process_item(cl, holder,position);
                    changeBg(holder,qty[0]);

                    holder.txtsubtotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    s_qty[0] = String.valueOf(qty[0]);
                    holder.txtqty.setText(s_qty[0]);
                    process_item(cl, holder,position);
                    holder.txtsubtotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,cl.getProduct() + " " + context.getResources().getString(R.string
                        .strsalesquantityerror1) +
                        " " + Products.getItemOnHand(context,String.valueOf(cl.getProdid())) + " " + context.getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.strsalesquantityerror2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.layview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(holder.imgminus.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                holder.imgminus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(qty[0] == 0) {
                    holder.imgadd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtqty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    holder.txtqty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgadd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.txtqty.setText(s_qty[0]);
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,SingeItem.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SOURCE,Constants.SALETYPE_SALE);
                intent.putExtra(Products.PRODUCTNAME,cl.getProdid());
                intent.putExtra(Products.ID, position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.txtqty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(holder.imgadd.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                holder.txtqty.setText(s_qty[0]);
                holder.imgadd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgminus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredIt.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0){
    return 0;
}


 private void updateViews(int qt, Vh holder){
    double un = unit[0];
    double st = new BigDecimal(qt).multiply(new BigDecimal(un)).doubleValue();
    s_qty[0] = String.valueOf(qt);
    s_subtotal[0] =  new BigDecimal(st).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();

    s_subtotal[0] = currency + " " + new BigDecimal(subtotal[0]).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
    s_unit = currency+" "+new BigDecimal(unit[0]).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();

    holder.txtsubtotal.setText(s_subtotal[0]);
    holder.txtunit.setText(s_unit);
    holder.txtsubtotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(qt > 0)
        imgnext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        imgnext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    gtotal += subtotal[0];
    txtt.setText(currency + " " + new BigDecimal(gtotal).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString());
    txti.setText("/ " + items + " " + context.getString(R.string.stritems));
}


  }
```

Comment: I don't have the solution but i think you need to update one item at a time. The way you are doing it will only affect the last visible item.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Let me try to see way to overcome that

Answer (score 1):

1) At a time if you want to show/hide only one element this one work fine

**Step1)**
  create a variable and set its value to=-1;
      int currentPosition=-1;

**Step2)**
  On bind viewHolder,on itemClick update currentPosition to holder position

```
onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder v,int position)
            {
              view.Onclick(...{currentPosition=position;});
              if(currentPosition==position)
                view.setVisiblity(Visible);
              else
               view.setVisibility(Gone);  
           }
```

2) If you want to show more item on any button click then

1. Create 2 arrayList,first arrayList store total value and second
   arrayList display only few elements in holder;
2. now on button click add all element to other arrayList and notify.